# How can I get the full URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url

How can I get the full URL, like `http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=someid&page=1`, not just `http://www.domain.com/page.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` has the query string portion of the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

Comment: so PHP_SELF + QUERY_STRING should do it?

Comment: IIRC, `$PHP_SELF` doesn't include the hostname - you'd want to add `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` for that.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, as Zied suggested?

Answer (score 3):

A quick answer:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```